# openpyxl set nunmber format to cell but doesn't work

Tags: python, csv, openpyxl

I want to create an excel by reading data from the csv files.
So, I use Openpyxl and CSV in python.
However, no matter `number_format` I put in the code the cell value from the csv remain in 'text' format

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv
from openpyxl.styles import numbers

ws= load_workbook('myworkbook.xlsx')    
with open("myfile.csv", "r", newline="", encoding="utf16") as f:
    mydata=csv.reader(f,delimiter='|')
    for row in mydata:
        for col_index,col_data in enumerate(row,3):
            ws.cell(row=new800row_count, column=col_index, value=col_data).number_format = numbers.FORMAT_NUMBER
```

let's say my csv file contains 800, 200, 100 data value.
After using my  code above. Instead of showing 800, 200, 100 in number format (excel) it's told me that this cell contain number stored as text even the actual excel format told me that it's a number

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: Everything in a CSV is a string so you need to convert the relevant values to numbers in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Loop through your data set, convert the data if its a string to float:

```
str = '1234.0'
data = float(str)
row[col] = data
row[col].number_format = '#,##0.00'
```

The last line of code ensures its formatted as a number. don't forget to save the file after making the above changes.

Comment: Is there a way to have the new `number_format` reflected in the `value` attribute of the cell, without saving and reloading the excel file?

Comment: This is a decent code example, but I highly recommend against using `str` as a variable name, given that it's a type name. Doesn't impact anything in this minimum viable example, but if someone isn't careful when copying bits of this, it could break their code. Maybe `s` or `text` would be better choices

Answer (score 0):

CSV reader is intended to be simple and will always give you text. Openpyxl also will not do the conversion implicitly. You need to convert the text into number first. For example, under the loop of each row:

```
row = [float(cell) if cell.isdigit() else cell for cell in row]
```

and then use the row as you wish.

Comment: Thanks. However, It doesn't work. But I notice that if I press the individual cell with 'F2' and enter. Column will automatically convert to number  since the cell format is number. So, Did you know how to refresh all the cell in the worksheet using python or VBA?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me, first, convert the value itself into the datatype that you need; i.e int/float. Then apply builtin format from the openpyxl.styles.numbers.

In case of int:

```
cell=ws.cell(row=new800row_count, column=col_index, value=int(col_data))
cell.number_format = '0'
```

In case of float:

```
cell=ws.cell(row=new800row_count, column=col_index, value=float(col_data))
cell.number_format = '0.00'
```

You can find more details on the builtin format for openpyxl.styles.numbers [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html)!.